# Logs of a docker container

Tags: docker

Where does docker store it logs in the host machine as well as in the docker container. I know you can use docker logs . I want to know what is the physical location. Here is any example to illustrate more. I have got a java application which is generating standard output logs. I am using the following script to run it on a docker container

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup java -jar /opt/pubsub/publish.jar &
java -jar /opt/pubsub/subscribe.jar
```

I am unable to find my nohup in the container however I can see the content of nohup using docker logs . So where is my nohup??

Secondly where are the logs which are generated by docker itself?

Comment: check https://docs.docker.com/userguide/usingdocker/ and https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout

Comment: You can drop the `nohup` now that you've added the "&". If you use two separate containers, you won't have this problem.

Comment: your **nohup.out** is in the directory from which you ran the above script. How did you run it exactly ?

Comment: I can't find it in the execution directory as well as the home directory. But when I run docker logs <container_id> I am able to see on the host OS

Answer (score 0):

They are stored in /var/lib/docker/containers

You can try docker-ci, it offers a solution to logging. It will watch the logs and send it to the client.

I hope this will help you.

http://docker-ci.org/documentation#remote-logging